# Browserify and global jQuery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, browserify

I'm using browserify in my WordPress theme. The problem I'm having is that I would like to include jQuery the "WordPress way" (i.e. `wp_enqueue_script('jquery')`) so that all WordPress plugins that rely on `window.jQuery` to be defined (and included in `<head>`) keep working.

I've managed to make browserify ignore jQuery requires simply by setting `browserify(conf).ignore('jquery')` in my Gulpfile.js but this results in scripts attempting to include jQuery the "browserify way" to fail.

How can I have a global jQuery object (included in its own `<script>` element in head) so that WP plugins work, and still have code that does `var $ = require('jquery')` work? Is it possible?

Update: I think I've gotten somewhat closer. I'm now including jQuery "normally" in `<head>`. I've set `ignore('jquery')` on my browserify call to avoid it ending up in my bundled file too AND I'm using browserify-shim (here's where I'm slightly lost) to (I think?) make it so that when you do `require('jquery')` it instead uses the global `window.jQuery` object?

This seems to work in my own code, if I do:

```
var foo = require('jquery');

console.dir(foo);
```

I do get a jQuery object, and yet my bundled file is only a few kb's indicating jQuery is *not* bundled in there. *However*, when I `npm install jquery-cycle` and require that from my script, I get a JS error from the jquery cycle code that $ is undefined. The strange part imo is that the cycle script does *exactly* what I did, that is `var $ = require('jquery')` but in there `$` is *not* a jQuery object at all, instead just an empty object. Why is this?

Update 2: For some reason, if I change my `require()` of the cycle plugin to instead require the exact JS file it works. IE I've changed `require('jquery-cycle')` (which threw an error basically saying `$ is undefined`) to `require('../node_modules/jquery-cycle/index.js')`.

I would of course very much prefer to keep requiring things the "normal" way. Any ideas why that refuses to work?

Update 3: After much digging I've finally found that one needs to set `global: true` to the `transform()` call in order for dependencies dependencies to also use the shimmed jQuery. I finally found this solution here: [Shimming dependencies of dependencies with browserify-shim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26024912/shimming-dependencies-of-dependencies-with-browserify-shim/26596279#26596279)

Comment: Are you compling gulp on the same host with Wordpress?

Comment: I'm doing everything locally atm if that's what you mean?

Comment: You may use even localy different host for running gulp to compile front-end files and http server for Wordpress.

Comment: If you do I think it would be difficult and senseless to connect them but if host is the same I maybe could suggest some options. Please tell how you run gulp and Wordpress

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what this has to do with my problem?

Comment: There's a good post on this here: https://webdevstudios.com/2015/09/03/modernize-wordpress-javascript/

Comment: @Pete thanks for that. I did manage to solve this though, just forgot to answer my own question. I essentially did exactly what he does in the article you linked to.

Answer (score 0):

> I do get a jQuery object, and yet my bundled file is only a few kb's indicating jQuery is not bundled in there. However, when I npm install jquery-cycle and require that from my script, I get a JS error from the jquery cycle code that $ is undefined. The strange part imo is that the cycle script does exactly what I did, that is var $ = require('jquery') but in there $ is not a jQuery object at all, instead just an empty object. Why is this?

If you have multiple jQuery on the page you have to add a global variable:

```
var $ = jQuery;
```